# Symfony 2 : 302 http status and exception

Tags: symfony, redirect

I have this problem I dont know how to resolve.

I am in a controller action method , I make a test and if this test is positive I want to redirect.

```
public function contentAction() {
    $response = $this->render('MyBundle:Default:content.html.twig');

    if(!is_object($agent)) {
       $response = $this->redirect($this->get('router')->generate('new_route', 
                    array('error_message_key' => $error_message)));
    } 

    return $response;    
}
```

With the redirection, I have an exception

```
Error when rendering "http://alternativefirst/app_dev.php/accueil/" (Status code is 302)
```

I cannot make this redirection ? why could it be ?

IMPORTANT THING : I call this controller action in a twig template with

```
{{ render(controller('MyBundle:Default:content')) }}
```

Comment: `if () {` what? `$this->render(MyBundle:Default:content.html.twig');` is missing a quotation mark before `MyBundle`

Comment: whatever, a condition

Comment: I need to see valid code - I can't help until I dismiss any potential parsing errors from your question (that you've verified as tested.)

Comment: ok... here is the condition

Answer (score 1):

Try the `generateUrl()` helper function for your redirect:

```
$response = $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('new_route', array(
    'error_message_key' => $error_message,
)));
```

Your actual problem is caused by [trying to send a redirect within a Twig template](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/symfony2/wjSJ7wYmOMw).

Comment: it causes the same problem but I forgot to say something that might be important... I update the post

Comment: @mlwacosmos Yeah that's pretty crucial. [See this Google group thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/symfony2/wjSJ7wYmOMw). Doing something like throwing a redirect within a Twig template is like trying to call a `header()` function after PHP has sent output.

Answer (score 1):

The solution would be to move the rendering and redirection logic into the `/accueil` controller action because as it is right now, you're attempting to perform a PHP header redirect on a page that has already been loaded, which isn't possible. Alternatively, you could perform a javascript `window.location` redirect inside the content.html template you're trying to load by doing something like this:

```
{% if agent is not defined %}<script>window.location = '{{ path('new_route') }}';</script>{% endif %}
```

You would have to pass along the agent object (or anything you want to use as the trigger), but that strikes me as a rather crude solution to what is likely an architectural problem in your code.