# Redirection when rendering controller in twig SYMFONY 302

Tags: javascript, php, html, symfony, twig

Hi I'm developping two applications now with Symfony 3,I have the same problem in both, I want to integrate a search form into twig with render(controller()), the problem is that redirecting to the result page gives me this error

An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Error when rendering "http://localhost/project/web/app_dev.php/index" (Status code is 302).").

this is my controller

```html
class ProductController extends Controller
{

    public function resultsAction($criteria){
     $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
     $listProducts = $em->getRepository('ProjectProductBundle:Product')->getListBy($criteria);
     return $this->render('ProjectFrontBundle:Front:results.html.twig', array('listProducts'=>$listProducts));
    }

    public function SearchByNameAction(Request $request){
        $product = new Product();
        $form=$this->get('form.factory')->create(ProductType::class,$product);
        if($request->isMethod('post') && $form->handleRequest($request)->isValid()){
            $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $criteria = $form["name"]->getData();
            
            return $this->redirectToRoute('project_product_results', array('criteria'=>$criteria));
        }

        return $this->render('ProductFrontBundle:Front:search.html.twig',array('form'=>$form->createView()));
    }
}
```

this is my function in repository

```html
class ProductRepository extends \Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
{
 public function getListBy($criteria)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
    ->where('p.name LIKE :criteria')
    ->setParameter('criteria', '%'.$criteria.'%');
    
return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}


}
```

this is my view on twig

```html
<div>
  {% block search_body %}
{{ render(controller('ProductProductBundle:Product:SearchByName',{'request': app.request,})) }}
{% endblock %}
  </div>
```

this is the view on twig resultss page

```html
<ul>
 {% for product in listProducts %}
<li>{{ product.name }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

I need your help how can i solve this problem ?

Comment: Apparently, you cannot redirect from an embedded controller. Possible duplicate [Symfony 2 : 302 http status and exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26042633/symfony-2-302-http-status-and-exception)

Comment: Please add your routing configuration for this action.

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is here. **A comma is too much in the parameters**. In general, there is no need to specify Request in the parameters, prototyping by Request $request allows an implicit recovery of the request.

```
<div>
    {% block search_body %}
        {{ render(controller('ProductProductBundle:Product:SearchByName')) }}
    {% endblock %}
</div>
```

Do not forget to add the use to the top of the controller :

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
```